# Object of type InlineKeyboardMarkup is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, bots, telegram

**MY CODE**

```
async def options(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Option 1", callback_data="1"),InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Option 2", callback_data="2")]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=keyboard)
    #InlineKeyboardMarkup([[keyboard]], **kwargs)


    await update.message.reply_text("Please choose:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Look out for possible solutions and still got the same error

**MY ERROR MESSAGE**

```
2024-01-17 01:13:30,998 - telegram.ext.Application - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_baserequest.py", line 330, in _request_wrapper
    code, payload = await self.do_request(
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_httpxrequest.py", line 242, in do_request
    data = request_data.json_parameters if request_data else None
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_requestdata.py", line 74, in json_parameters
    return {
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_requestdata.py", line 77, in <dictcomp>
    if param.json_value is not None
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_requestparameter.py", line 76, in json_value
    return json.dumps(self.value)
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\arkgn\anaconda3\envs\rsi_master\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type InlineKeyboardMarkup is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: It might make sense to first start with what you're trying to achieve, and then explain why this is the code you wrote and why you expected `InlineKeyboardMarkup` to be JSON serializable.

Comment: And please provide [mre]